# Два принятых ответа

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, принятые-ответы

Наткнулся тут на вопрос: [Как удалить элемент из выпадающего списка с помощью jQuery?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/401754/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery)

И в нём два принятых ответа. Может кто-то объяснить сей феномен?

Comment: Хы, круто) Видать косяк переезда с ХэшКода)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб наверное, одну красную надо бы всё же снять.

Comment: @alexolut два принятых ответа, две красных, всё норм)

Comment: @alexolut, не уверен) По-моему важно, что бага воспроизводилась)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб во-первых, есть история изменений. Во-вторых, метка всё же должна соответствовать текущему состоянию ситуации, иначе возможны варианты: статус-воспроизведено, статус-отложено, статус-завершено и т.п. одновременно. Зачем это всё?

Comment: @alexolut, хм... Убедительно, убираю)

Comment: Нет косяка.....

Comment: [Wayback Machine для любопытствующих](http://web.archive.org/web/20170328125544/https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/401754/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery)

Comment: @andreymal Круто, нам бы так)) Вдруг оба ответа хороши)

Comment: Замените ссылку на http://web.archive.org/web/20170328125544/https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/401754/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery , на вашей ссылке нет двх принятых ответов.

Comment: @VerNick есть, просто картинки галочек не сразу прогружаются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После того, как спросил про этот баг на MSE, его пофиксили: [2 accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316073/260198).

Теперь только [ответ от Автостопом_до_Рая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/401763/15479) отмечен как принятый.

Comment: А говорили, что никто кроме автора не может помечать галочкой и снимать её. Все врут!

Comment: @alexolut страшно жить, кругом враньё!

Answer (score 4):

Похоже на баг.

Если посмотреть [ответы пользователя VasyOk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/8222/vasyok?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=2), то можно заметить, что ответ на этот вопрос у него не принят.

А ответ пользователя [Автостопом_до_Рая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7165/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%8F?tab=answers) принят.